# align multiple divs css

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can align multiple divs in a set possision I woild like container1 to be on the left, container to be in the center, container 3 to be on the right all nect to each other. and lastly I want container2 to be below container in the center bottom. please help if you don't understand please ask

```html
<div class="container1" style="border-width:1px; float: left; border-style:solid; width:350px; height:500px;  z-index:1; visibility:; background-color: lightgrey;visibility:;">


  container1

</div>

<center>
  <div class="container" style="background-color:lightgrey; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; width:500px; height:500px;  z-index:1; visibility:; float: center; visibility:; background-color: lightgrey;visibility:;">

    container
  </div>
</center>

<div class="container3" style="border-width:1px; float: right; border-style:solid; width:350px; height:500px;  z-index:1; visibility:; background-color: lightgrey;visibility:;">

  container3
</div>
<div class="container2" style="border-width:1px; float: bott; border-style:solid; width:500px; height:100px;  z-index:1; visibility:; background-color: lightgrey;visibility:;">

  container 2
</div>
​
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, may I note that the `<center>` element is deprecated and nearly obsolete (use a block element with `text-align: center`), and that CSS declarations are generally preferred over inline styles, because it's easier to debug and much more powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write css for .container1, .container & .container3 as "`float: left`". .container2 should not have any type float